# <he's vs he is> at the end of a clause

Tags: contractions

> 1. He used to be much better off than he's now.

Is the contraction "he's" correct here？ Or should it be:

> 2. He used to be much better off than he **is** now.

The reason why I ask is that I was taught that at the end of a sentence, we cannot use the contracted form of  words.  But i am not sure if the rule still applies when there is "now" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, (1) is not correct. The sentence compares past and present - **used to be** and **is** - so the word 'is' needs to be emphasised.